# Kubernetes pods are not scheduled even when nodes has memory available

Tags: kubernetes, scheduling, amazon-eks, autoscaling

Hello we are using kubernetes worker nodes as t3.xlarge (4 cpu and 16 Gi memory) in AWS EKS , now we have increased pods memory and CPU for 8-9 pods as 2 core cpu's and 4 Gi memory each, now many of my pods are in pending state , mentioning no node has enough capacity . I have nodes resources available as follows

[image]

there are some nodes with less than 20% memory and CPU utilization but still my pods are in pending state, why my kubernetes scheduler not scheduling pods in available nodes??

Want to understand how to handle this efficiently

Comment: Aside from this blatantly off-topic question, please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 0):

The k8s scheduler does not consider the actual utilization of resources for scheduling decisions(If request values are specified) but it considers the allocated resources of nodes. You can use `kubectl describe node <node-name>` command to check the allocated resources of nodes.

Now as you said Pod's memory and CPU values are changed, I am not sure if these are Request or Limit values. But if these changes are in Request values, it will affect scheduling.

So to resolve issue, either revisit request values of pods based on current cluster allocation or increase cluster size.